# Geoserver WFS Layer - Partially loads data

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-pro, wfs

I have published a point file (1.4mil points) to my Geoserver.
I created a WFS connection in my ArcGIS Pro 2.3, and the features load up in the WFS list.

I add the point file to my map and some points load, but a "Repair Connection" error sits next to the layer in the ToC. I can't see how many points load or view any of the attributes. See below:

[image]

I thought it was a settings issue, so upped the number of features that could be retrieved to over 5 million..

I loaded the same data as a WMS and it loaded perfectly.

I took the WFS and loaded it into QGIS, and all 1.4million points made it through and I was able to view and query the data with no issue.

Is there a "trick" to loading a WFS from Geoserver into ArcGIS Pro?

The Geoserver has a few WFS test / demo layers, these too will not load in ArcGIS, but load fine in QGIS.

My geoserver is version **2.17.0**
My ArcGIS Pro is **2.3.0**

Comment: From what you describe, the title `partial loads data` seems incorrect. it appears that ArcGIS Pro can read the GetCapabilities response from the WFS server, and possibly a DescribeFeatureType, but can't fetch any data (GetFeature).    Is the WFS serving simple features?

Comment: It can sometimes be useful to run Fiddler, and inspect the requests that ArcGIS makes. Also, since 2.3 is already ~2.5 years old, maybe it's time to upgrade to a newer version? Perhaps WFS support has been improved since?

Comment: Thank you both. @nmtoken I am not sure I fully understand your comment, but will use it to Google thank you. Berend I will try upgrade. Company IT policy might block it.

Comment: So e.g. with QGIS you give the WFS endpoint, it does a GetCapabilities to get layer information, you select a featuretype, it does first a DescribeFeatureType request then a GetFeature.  The data comes with the GetFeature response; the others are metadata